# Codeigniter base_url on main site is pointing to dev site and vice versa

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

Here's a weird problem I've never encountered.

I'm working with a client on redesigning his page. His main navigation is defined by

```
?php echo site_url('create-a-shipment')?
```

Now, when you go to the page, the link is set to dev.thewebsite.com. Upon clicking you're brought to the dev site, but when you mouse over the links again it's set to "thewebsite.com". So it seems to think that the base URL on the main site is the dev site and vice versa.

I've checked the config file in CodeIgniter and both are set correctly. I've also checked RewriteBase/ in the .htaccess on the dev site.

Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like the problem is more localized to your actual anchor

Comment: Have you set base url? In codeigniter 3 you might run in to issues if you don't